# What value are alpha/beta to begin with in Minimax algorithm?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I understand the algorithm, as it applies to Alpha-Beta pruning. What I don't understand is since there is no way to represent ∞ in Java, on my first call to the `Minimax` method, what value should `Alpha` and `Beta` be to start out with? (Normally I would think you could make them `-∞` and `+∞`). The only thing I could think of would be 0, but would that produce some unwanted results? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the data type you're using.  `-∞` and `+∞` simply mean the lowest and highest values possible.

If you pick `int`, the respective values can be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The algorithm will work just fine.

Also, infinity can be represented in Java. If you really want to, you can use `float`, which [has both a positive and negative infinity value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY). You could just use `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. For this algorithm,though, I'd stick with integers. Just because they're free from all possibly unexpected behavior related to rounding and precision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didnt know that about &infin; and Java! Other guy answered first :)

Answer (score 4):

```
int alpha = Integer.MIN_VALUE
int beta = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Best you can do with no infinity.